# Elasticsearch multi match exact match boosting

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We use spring data elastic search. 
We use multimatch query to search against multiple fields.

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = multiMatchQuery(searchInput, "id","firstName","lastName","title","nickName","location")
        .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX).analyzer("standard");
```

We use PHRASE_PREFIX for phrase match.

Now, we would like to add boosting for exact match on nickName( boosting only if exact match ).

For example, when i search for Phone, if there is a exact match on nickName, it should be ordered first in the result. If there is no exact match, then firstName should be given boosting. I tried boosting like below.

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = multiMatchQuery(searchInput, "id","firstName","lastName","title","nickName^9","location")
        .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX).analyzer("standard");
```

Boosting doesnt seem to be working. Also not sure, how to add boosting only on exact match on a field.

Thanks